# Spring Security @PreAuthorize on controller method not invoked

Tags: spring, security, controller

I'm trying to use Spring Security (3.2.4) to authorise access to controller methods. I'm using Spring JavaConfig to configure my application. The application starts successfully, unfortunately the @PreAuthoize expression never gets executed.

Here's how I've configured my application:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebSecurityConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class<?>[] {WebAppConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] {"/"};
  }

}

public class WebAppSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ CoreAppConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ControllerScanningMarker.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

At the moment, I'm not actually authenticating any users so I was expecting that access to a @PreAuthorize annotated controller method would be denied to everyone but that's not happening. Obviously, the end goal is to actually authenticate users as well.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
  }

  @Bean 
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RegistrationController {

  @Autowired
  private RegistrationService registrationService;

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}/registrations", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public RegistrationResponse registerVerification(@PathVariable String orderId, @RequestBody @Valid Registration registration) {
    RegistrationResult result = registrationService.registerVerification(registration);
    return new RegistrationResponse(result);
  }

}
```

If anyone has seen something like this before, I would greatly appreciate a tip.

Thank you.

**Updated 11/07/2014**

I have revisited this and fixed the issue with the authentication manager not being found but I still can't get the @PreAuthorize annotation to work (see all changes above).

I'm getting the following warnings in the logs:

```
00:04:06.090 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@5c694679' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:04:06.154 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'enableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:04:06.161 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$47d25495] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:04:06.188 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6313a932] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:04:06.223 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:04:06.229 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Comment: You haven't configured Spring Security so nothing is being checked. Add another `WebApplicationInitializer` to setup Spring Security's filter chain. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer.

Comment: I have made changes (above) as per your comment and spring documentation but I'm still not getting the @PreAuthorise expression to trigger.

Comment: Your `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` has to be placed on your `WebAppConfig`. It will register some AOP stuff and that wil only be applied in the same context it is configured in. When loaded in the root context it doesn't do a thing for the servlet context.

Comment: I've tried adding the EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to the WebAppConfig but then it complained about not being able to find the authentication manager. After I copied the registerGlobal method from WebSecurityConfig the application started successfully but still does not evaluate the PreAuthorize expression. I've also tried, adding the security config to the servlet context and a few other silly things but nothing has worked. I wonder if perhaps adding PreAuthorize on a controller method is not the right way to do this. All examples that I've seen so far only do it on service methods.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the `@PreAuthorize` annotations, although putting them on controllers can be harder due to the fact that the proxy might break detection of the other annotations. The error you get about not being able to find the authentication manager makes me wonder if you have configured things properly. Make sure that everything is loaded properly.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is working! What was happening is `@Valid` annotation was getting precedence and I was getting a validation error. My expectation was that `@PreAuthorize` would be executed first but it looks like that's not happening, which is very strange, logically you would think that any authorisation logic would happen before anything else. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to define users and roles for my application in my implementation of 
`protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` in my security configurer class. 
`auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").roles("user","otherrole").and().withUser("user2").roles("otherrole")`
The `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` annotation denied access to user2 but not to user on controller methods annotated

Answer (score 0):

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) work in java config